# Javascript canvas how to drawImage a lot of images

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How i can draw a lot of image in canvas?

I have a lot of images url array and need output it. How to do with good perfomance.

me example code (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6sunguw4/):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var bgCanvas = document.getElementById("bgCanvas");
            var bgCtx = bgCanvas.getContext("2d");

            bgCanvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            bgCanvas.height = window.innerHeight + 200;


            var array = new Array();
            array[1] = 'https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images/calendar.png';
            array[2] = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif';
            array[3] = 'http://www.linosartele.lt/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/images-9.jpg';

            img0 = new Image();
            img0.onload = function() {
                bgCtx.drawImage(img0, 0,0, 100, 100);
            }
            img0.src = array[1];


            img2 = new Image();
            img2.onload = function() {
                bgCtx.drawImage(img2, 100,0, 100, 100);
            }
            img2.src = array[2];

            img3 = new Image();
            img3.onload = function() {
                bgCtx.drawImage(img3, 200,0,100,100);
            }
            img3.src = array[3];
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's code to load all images from the URLs you put into your array without having to hand code 2000 times `new Image/.onload/.drawImage`  (I call the array imageURLs in the example code below):

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
// push all your image urls!
imageURLs.push('https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/images/calendar.png');
imageURLs.push('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5.gif');
imageURLs.push('http://www.linosartele.lt/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/images-9.jpg');

// the loaded images will be placed in imgs[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

    bgCtx.drawImage(imgs[0], 000,0, 100, 100);
    bgCtx.drawImage(imgs[1], 100,0, 100, 100);
    bgCtx.drawImage(imgs[2], 200,0, 100, 100);

}
```

**For better loading performance:**

Browsers typically download only 6-8 files at a time from one domain.  So your 2000 images would require 2000/8 == 250 separate sequential calls to your domain to load.

You can combine your 2000 into one or more spritesheets (preferably 6 or less spritesheets).  That way the browser can download the 1-6 spritesheets containing your 2000 images in one trip.

You can use the extended version of context.drawImage to pull any desired image from the spritesheet.  For example, assume an image you need is located at [200,200] on your spritesheet and is 100x100 in size. You can draw that image on your canvas like this:

```
bgCtx.drawImage(spritesheet,
    200,200,100,100    // clip the image from the spritesheet at [200,200] with size 100x100
    125,250,100,100    // draw the clipped image on the canvas at [125,250]
);
```

Comment: @Asker. Remove `img.crossOrigin="anonymous"` and it should work.  I set this flag by default in my own projects but if you're loading cross-domain images it must be removed.   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There's not much you can do with the code itself. drawImage seems pretty optimized, and it's the raw amount of images what could slow things down.

One thing you can maybe do, depending on your goal, is to prepare composite images. For example, those 3 images could be easily converted into a single PNG image, and then it would require only one drawImage call. However, if you plan to shift their places or some effects, I'm afraid you're stuck with what you have.

Comment: how to output all array because i have a lot of images about 2000, i cannot write hands..

Comment: Loop through the array and draw each. What are you trying to achieve, and why canvas?